# Javascript (ES6 + Lodash) merge source object with another updating only common properties, deeply

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have to deeply update an object with a provided one
, keeping only the properties/paths found in the source object.
I tried Lodash.merge, but it merges all the properties of the second object, I want to merge only the properties found in the source object.

Here is an example:

```
const ob1 = {
  a1: {
    b1: 2
  },
  a2: 5
}

const obj2 = {
  a1: {
    b1: 4,
    b2: 9
  },
  a3: 6
}

expected result = {
  a1: {
    b1: 4
  },
  a2: 5
}
```

I'd like the simplest solution with es6 or lodash utils.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: _"I tried Lodash.merge"_ may you show us this?

Comment: What if `obj2` doesn't have a key which is present in `obj1`? Should that be removed from `obj1` or set as undefined?

Comment: if the key is present in obj1 and not in obj2 it should be kept as found in obj1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a custom merge strategy, perhaps you can write your own recursive function. In the recursive function, you basically pass in your target and your source. Based on your question, the target will be `obj1` and the source will be `obj2`.

Your logic is that:

1. If `obj1` does not contain a key that is in `obj2`, we keep the key-value pair from the `obj1`, the source
2. If `obj1` contains a key that is `obj2`, then:

   - If they are simply non-objects, we allow `obj2` value to override `obj1` value
   - If they are both objects, then we call the same recursive function again

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const obj1 = {
  a1: {
    b1: 2
  },
  a2: 5
}

const obj2 = {
  a1: {
    b1: 4,
    b2: 9
  },
  a3: 6
}

function smartMerge(target, source) {
  const o = {};
  
  // Iterate throught all keys in your target
  for(let k in target) {
  
    // If a matching key is found in source
    if (k in source) {
      // If they are both objects, then we run recurisve merge logic
      if (typeof target[k] === 'object' && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
        o[k] = smartMerge(target[k], source[k]);
      }
      // Otherwise, we let the source override the value
      else {
        o[k] = source[k];
      }
    }
    
    // If no matching key is found, we keep the target value
    else {
      o[k] = target[k];
    }
  }
  
  return o;
}

const result = smartMerge(obj1, obj2);

/* Expected:
{
  a1: {
    b1: 4
  },
  a2: 5
}
*/
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```